# Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function // in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Its strange because i just did ctrl+z until the point that the app was running good but its just stuck on that error so i cant just move on, the add users button works well but the console go just crazy on infinite loops, i just dont get it but at the same point its just a firebase/firestore CRUD => meaning its BASIC asf.
This is the code

```
import "./App.css";
import BooksList from "./components/BooksList";
import { db } from "./firebase-config";

import {
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  addDoc,
  doc,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  setDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  where,
  updateDoc
} from "firebase/firestore";

const App = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  // collection ref
  const colRef = collection(db, "books"); // f(x) collection => firebase/firestore => te permite seleccionar la collection especifica => collection(1param=> db, 2doParam 'collectionName')

  useEffect(() =>
    onSnapshot(  // REAL TIME LISTENER
      collection(db, "books"),
      (
        snapShot //onSnapShot => f(X) que permite hacer un fetch de data y que los cambios se vean enseguida en el render / Sino tendrias que apretar f5
      ) =>
        setBooks(snapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))),
      []
    )
  );

  /* 
    const createBook = async () =>{
      const docRef = doc(db, 'books', 'books001' ) // path => hace referencia a => collection
      const payload = {title: title, author: author}
      await setDoc(docRef, payload) // Setea un document => de hecho le agrega un id unico al created. => Si pones un Id que ya existe => lo sobreEscribe
    } */

    //CREATE
  const createBook = async () => {
    // Creation Method
    const payload = { title, author };
    addDoc(colRef, payload);
  };

/*   const updateBook = async (id) =>{   
    const docRef = doc(db, 'books', id)
    const newFields = {title:'Lo he cambiaaaao'}
    await updateDoc(docRef, newFields)

  } */


  //DELETE  => Super simple => el method es deleteDoc(docRef => doc() y el id que lo sacas del button onClick dentro del map) OJOOO => Este es un caso donde queres hacer un delete completo de 1 elemento, => Ahora veremos por nombre y cosas mas complejas. 
  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    const docRef = doc(db, 'books', id)
    console.log(id);
    //const payload = {} => No hay payload necesario => No estas updateando ni creando nada => tenes el id => ELIMINAR y chau 
   await deleteDoc(docRef)
  }

  const handleQueryDelete = async () =>{ 
    const deletedTitle = prompt('Enter the name of the title you want to delete') // Title

    const q = query(colRef, where('title','==', deletedTitle) ) // Acá aprendi a ponerle condiciones al fetch => f(x)=> query

    const snapshot = await getDocs(q)
    
    const results = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id}))
    console.log(results)

/*     results.forEach( async result =>{
        const docRef= (db, 'books', result.id )
        await deleteDoc(docRef)
    }) */

  }

  return (
    <div>
      {books.map((book) => {
        return (
          <div className='bg-red-200 mx-auto my-5 flex justify-around items-center'  key={book.id}>
            <BooksList book={book} />
            <button className='bg-red-400 text-white p-3 rounded-md border-black border-1'
            onClick={()=>handleDelete(book.id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
         {/*    <button className='bg-yellow-500 text-gray-800 p-3 rounded-xl border-black border-2'
            onClick={()=>updateBook(book.id)}
            >
              Update
            </button> */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div className='bg-blue-800 flex justify-center items-center' >
      <button 
      onClick={()=> handleQueryDelete()}
      className="bg-violet-600 text-white p-3 rounded-md border-black border-1" >Delete by query</button>
      </div  >
      <button onClick={createBook}>Create</button>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Title..."
      />
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Author..."
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any help will be very appreaciated, im just starting with firebase, not with the right feet i c tho haha

Comment: Can you provide more details on the error? Like which part of the code is likely the cause ?

Comment: Ya, of course, the error jumped when i was trying to make an update, it was this code ```/*   const updateBook = async (id) =>{   
    const docRef = doc(db, 'books', id)
    const newFields = {title:'Lo he cambiaaaao'}
    await updateDoc(docRef, newFields)

  } */``` The complete erros says this ```index.esm2017.js:13888 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
    at index.esm2017.js:13888```

Comment: Well, just found out what happened, i just reached out the limit of firestore free storage features. just went to the database and that was the message, thank u very much tho! @Dharmaraj

Comment: I am getting the same error message on RN + Expo 47 + Firebase v9, and we are definitely NOT out of free storage (because we pay). It looks like Firebase v9, in an effort to go modular, has done something that Expo and Metro can't deal with. Adding "cjs" as an extension in the `metro.config.js` solved the first issue we had but now I'm stuck here, and striking out all over the internet.

Comment: @ipmcc Did you find a way to fix your issue? I'm going through the same issue "t is not a function." After upgrading to Firebase v9.

Comment: Follow up to my comment above. We upgraded to Expo 47 and deleted the "unimodules" package. Ran yarn. Installed some new packages. And the app started working as expected.